# Adding a table of appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, appendix

I have several tables in my appendix, but am unsure how to create a table of appendices. So far, my tables from the appendix show up in the "List of tables" but I would like to have them separately and named Appendix1, Appendix2 etc.

The finale table of appendices should look like this:

```
List of Attachments

Appendix1: Your second table…………………………………………………………xi
```

I would be very thankful for any help on this!

MWE (see below)

The table "Your second table" should appear in the table of appendices. The table "Your first table" in the list of tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoftables

\clearpage

\section{Empirical Results}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Your first table.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{l|c|r}
      \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
      $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
      \hline
      1 & 1110.1 & a\\
      2 & 10.1 & b\\
      3 & 23.113231 & c\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\appendix
\section*{Appendix} \label{appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Your second table.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{l|c|r}
      \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
      $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
      \hline
      1 & 1110.1 & a\\
      2 & 10.1 & b\\
      3 & 23.113231 & c\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Don't use the `center` environment as it adds extra space, use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}` and delete `\end{center}`.